# How to create dynamic stats for dynamic range sliders in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating multiple range sliders using map (means dynamic)
I wants to set range values(min & max) for every range slider. how to do that ? Please check my code..

[image]

//RANGE SLIDER

```
{
    [...Array(fields.field_count)].map((item, index) => {
        return (

            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Controller
                    control={control}
                    name={fields.field_name[index]}
                    defaultValue=""
                    key={fields.field_name[index]}
                    render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                        <View>
                            <RangeSlider
                                min={fields.min[0]}
                                max={fields.max[0]}
                                step={0.1}
                                floatingLabel={true}
                                allowLabelOverflow={true}
                                renderThumb={renderThumb}
                                renderRail={renderRail}
                                renderRailSelected={renderRailSelected}
                                renderLabel={renderLabel}
                                renderNotch={renderNotch}
                                onValueChanged={handleValueChange}
                            />
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", width: 300, top: 5, }}>
                                <Text style={styles.silderText}>{low} mm</Text>
                                <View>
                                    <Text style={[styles.silderText,{right:15   }]}>{high} mm</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>

                    )}
                />
            </View>




        );
    })
}
```

// Value Handler

```
const handleValueChange = useCallback((low, high) => {
    setLow(low);
    setHigh(high);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
[...Array(fields.field_count)].map((item, index) => {
    return (

        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Controller
                control={control}
                name={fields.field_name[index]}
                defaultValue=""
                key={fields.field_name[index]}
                render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                    <View>
                        <RangeSlider
                            min={fields.min[0]}
                            max={fields.max[0]}
                            step={0.1}
                            floatingLabel={true}
                            allowLabelOverflow={true}
                            renderThumb={renderThumb}
                            renderRail={renderRail}
                            renderRailSelected={renderRailSelected}
                            renderLabel={renderLabel}
                            renderNotch={renderNotch}
                            onValueChanged={handleValueChange}
                        />
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", width: 300, top: 5, }}>
                            <Text style={styles.silderText}>{low} mm</Text>
                            <View>
                                <Text style={[styles.silderText,{right:15   }]}>{high} mm</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
})
}
```